# Custom init on test/development mode in Grails

Tags: groovy, grails

I want to run specific login in BootStrap class depending on development or test mode is currently used.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import grails.util.Environment

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        def currentEnv = Environment.current

        if (currentEnv == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
            // do custom init for dev here

        } else if (currentEnv == Environment.TEST) {
            // do custom init for test here

        } else if (currentEnv == Environment.PRODUCTION) {
            // do custom init for prod here
        }
     }

     def destroy = {
     }
}
```

Comment: This is the old way. Grails now supports an `environments` block in BootStrap.groovy just like in Config.groovy and DataSource.groovy - see "Per Environment Bootstrapping" in section 3.2 of the docs.

Answer (score 13):

From [the documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html):

```
class Bootstrap {
    def init = { ServletContext ctx ->
        environments {
            production {
                // prod initialization
            }
            test {
                // test initialization
            }
            development {
                // dev initialization
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the official docs

Programmatic Environment Detection

Within your code, such as in a Gant script or a bootstrap class you can detect the environment using the GrailsUtil class:

```
import grails.util.GrailsUtil
...
switch(GrailsUtil.environment) {
    case "development":
       configureForDevelopment()
    break
    case "production":
       configureForProduction()
    break
```